# Altair selection error: "Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector074_index""

Tags: python, altair

I've been trying to replicate the text shown by selection of the following chart with [this code](https://scikit-hep.org/pyhf/examples/notebooks/altair.html):

[image]

But I get the following error:
`Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector074_index" This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.`

I have dedicated all day trying to find out what I am doing wrong without any luck. Here's my code as a sample:

```
confirmed_area = alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).mark_area(fillOpacity=0).encode(
    alt.X('index:T', title=" "),
    alt.Y('confirmed:Q', title=" "),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('index:T', title="Fecha"), alt.Tooltip('confirmed:Q', title="Casos acumulados"), alt.Tooltip('confirmed_daily:Q', title="Nuevos Casos")]
).properties(
    height = 200,
    width = 800
).interactive(

)


confirmed_line = alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).mark_line(size=3).encode(
    alt.X('index:T', title=" "),
    alt.Y('confirmed:Q', title=" ")
).properties(
    height = 200,
    width = 800,
).interactive(

)

nearest = alt.selection_single(
    nearest=True, on="mouseover", fields=["index:T"], empty="none"
)


point = (
    alt.Chart(df.reset_index())
    .mark_point(color="black")
    .encode(x="index:T", y="confirmed:Q", opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(1), alt.value(0)))
    .add_selection(nearest)
)

text =confirmed_line.mark_text(align="left", dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, "confirmed:Q", alt.value(" "))
)

confirmed_line + confirmed_area + point + text
```

Comment: Is it reproduced with the same data as the example you are referring to? Or is it your own data? If it's your own data, isn't it too much to ask for an answer unless you can provide toy data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR – remove `.interactive()` from the definition of `confirmed_line`.

The issue is that you called `.interactive()` on a chart, and then layered it with itself. A minimal reproduction of this error looks like this:

```python
import altair as alt
chart = alt.Chart('data.txt').mark_point().interactive()
chart + chart
# Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector001_tuple"
# This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.
```

To fix this, you should only call `.interactive()` on one of the layers:

```python
import altair as alt
chart = alt.Chart('data.txt').mark_point()
chart + chart.interactive()
```

In your code, you call `.interactive()` when defining `confirmed_line`, and then derive `confirmed_text` from this, so that when it is layered there are two identical interactions on in one layer, which is not allowed. If you remove this call from `confirmed_line`, your chart should work: the `.interactive()` call on the `confirmed_area` layer already specifies that the axes should be interactive.